# Java: Reverse string via a delimiter

Tags: java, string, algorithm, reverse

I am trying to reverse the characters in a string separated by a delimiter I provide.

Input: `string: "Abc.134dsq"` , `delimiter: "."`

Desired Output: `cbA.qsd431`

My attempt:

```
String fileContent = "Abc.134dsq";
String delimiter = ".";
fileContent = fileContent.replace(delimiter, "-");
String[] splitWords = fileContent.split("-");
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (String word : splitWords) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(word).reverse();
    stringBuilder.append(output);
}

System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: (1) split string by delimiter, (2) reverse each part, (3) join it back together. Which step you have trouble with? Please show us your best attempt. (BTW each step has already separate question dedicated to it on Stack Overflow).

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here is one way in a single statement in Java 8+, but you probably won't understand it, since if you could, you would have been able to write at least some part of a solution yourself, so if you need any helpful solution, you need to be more specific in the question. Anyway, here it is: `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(".")).splitAsStream("Abc.134dsq").map(s->new StringBuilder(s).reverse()).collect(Collectors.joining("."))`

Comment: @Andreas This worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Be aware that my solution will remove any trailing `.`, as will the code added to the question.

Comment: I just ran into that same problem(it removed the trailing `.` for sample input `BCTVW.`). How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays
    .stream("Abc.134dsq".split("\\.", -1))
    .map(StringBuilder::new)
    .map(StringBuilder::reverse)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(".")));
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/4uyu7d).

This handles the “preserving the trailing dot” scenarios mentioned in the comments. Live demo shows this aspect too.

Enough time has passed that your homework deadline has passed, so I thought I’d show you this one-liner.