# JAVA: Delimiter removed when reversing a string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, reverse

How can I include the delimiter when reversing my string via code below?

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("."))
       .splitAsStream("BCTVW.")
       .map(s->new StringBuilder(s).reverse())
       .collect(Collectors.joining("."))
```

Current output: `WVTCB.`
Desired output: `.WVTCB`

The delimiter is missing from the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use non-capturing groups, e.g. lookahead.

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=\\.)")
             .splitAsStream("BCTVW.")
             .map(s->new StringBuilder(s).reverse())
             .collect(Collectors.joining("."));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Pattern(regex).splitAsStream(data)` has similar functionality as `data.split(regex)` so it also *removes trailing empty strings created as result of splitting*.
For instance `"a,b,".split(",")` would NOT result in `["a","b",""]` but `["a","b"]` because empty strings at the end of array would be removed.

Most crucial difference between `Pattern#splitAsStream` and `String#split` is that `String#split(regex)` method has *overloaded* version `String#split(regex, limit)` where `limit` depending on value affects its result.

If limit is

- `positive` it sets maximal amount of elements in resulting array like `"a,b,c,d".split(",", 3)` would result in `["a", "b", "c,d"]`.
- `0` it causes removal of trailing empty strings (`split(regex,0)` is same as `split(regex)`
- `negative` - ***prevents `split` from removing trailing empty strings*** - this is what you are after.

So don't use `Pattern#splitAsStream` but instead `String#split` method like you tried in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61022095):

> *quotation in case previous question would be removed*
>
> ```
> String fileContent = "Abc.134dsq";
> String delimiter = ".";
> fileContent = fileContent.replace(delimiter, "-");
> String[] splitWords = fileContent.split("-");
> StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
> for (String word : splitWords) {
>     StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(word).reverse();
>     stringBuilder.append(output);
> }
>
> System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
> ```

Things you need to correct there:

1. DONT replace `delimiter` in your string to `-` to split on `-` because your string may contain its own `-`. For instance `"A.B-C"` after replacing `.` to `-` will become `A-B-C` which will result in unwanted splitting `B-C`.

   Instead split using `Pattern.quote(delimiter)` - like you did in example provided in current question.
2. Use `split` with negative limit parameter to prevent removing trailing empty strings (something like `fileContent.split(Pattern(delimiter), -1)`)
3. You are not adding delimiters back to resulting string. Easy solution would be using `StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(delimiter);` `joiner.add(reversedElement)` instead of `StringBuilder` because `joiner.add` will also handle adding delimiter between elements we want to join.

Comment: This is very close. The only problem now is the delimiter is removed when I applied your changes. How can I add the delimiters back in?
```String fileContent = "def  mnop.STU";
String delimiter = "[^a-zA-Z0-9']+";
Current output: fedponmUTS
Desired output: fed  ponm.UTS```

Comment: @ChrisSmith "*problem now is the delimiter is removed when I applied your changes*" not quite. My suggestion about using `new SringJoiner(delimiter)` instead of `new StringBuilder()` should handle adding delimiters back to resulting string. Real problem is that you are changing now assumptions for task you want to solve, which  means you are changing question into different one. Provided answers are based on assumption that *delimiter is NOT a regex* but simple literal (since `.` is treated as symbol, not as "any character" which would happen for regex).

Comment: @ChrisSmith If you have similar question but based on different assumptions then please ask it in separate post and judge answers by questions you actually asked, not on what you *wanted* to ask...

Comment: Sure thing. I will create a separate post. Thanks for the help.